# WordPress: http request ip address different from website's

Tags: wordpress, api, xmlhttprequest

*IP addresses below are foo*

I have a WordPress site being hosted by a third party provider. When I ping this site, I get the IP address 50.51.52.53.

There is a part of code on this site that submits an http request to a permissioned API. Permissioned meaning the requester needs their IP whitelisted by the API service. I am using function wp_remote_get() to make the request. When this is made, it is denied (403). The php error log reveals that the http request came from IP address 60.61.62.63, not the address I had whitelisted 50.51.52.53.

My question is what is the reason for this discrepancy? Thanks in advance! I am a front end developer with little experience in networking/backend stuff.

Comment: Did you solve this as I have the same problem.